# Array of templated type in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have the following :

```
QFutureWatcher<bool> *procwatcher;
procwatcher = new QFutureWatcher<bool>();
QFuture<bool> procfuture = QtConcurrent::run(this, &EraserBatch::processTile);
procwatcher->setFuture(procfuture);

  QFutureWatcher<bool> *procwatcher2;
  procwatcher2 = new QFutureWatcher<bool>();
  QFuture<bool> procfuture2 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &EraserBatch::processTile);
  procwatcher2->setFuture(procfuture2);
```

What is the syntax for creating a dynamically sized array of these two types - QFutureWatcher and QFuture so that I can say procwatcher[0] and procfuture[1], etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `these`. Do you want a dynalloced array of *pointers to* `QFutureWatcher<bool>`, or an dynalloced array of `QFutureWatcher<bool>`?

Comment: edited the post to give some context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the template is fully specialized (i.e. all template parameters specified), then you can simply do this:

```
#include <vector> // required for std::vector

std::vector<QFutureWatcher<bool>*> procWatchers;
```

<strike>Although according to how `QFutureWatcher` is used in [these documentation examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuturewatcher.html), you probably want to store `QFutureWatcher` instances in the `std::vector` instead:</strike>

```
std::vector<QFutureWatcher<bool> > procWatchers;
```

That way you won't have to manually `new` and `delete` the `QFutureWatcher` instances.

Apparently [`QFutureWatcher` inherits from `QObject`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuturewatcher.html), which is [uncopyable](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor). That prevents `std::vector<QFutureWatcher<bool> >` from working.

---

You have this:

```
QFutureWatcher<bool> *procwatcher;
procwatcher = new QFutureWatcher<bool>();
QFuture<bool> procfuture = QtConcurrent::run(this, &EraserBatch::processTile);
procwatcher->setFuture(procfuture);

QFutureWatcher<bool> *procwatcher2;
procwatcher2 = new QFutureWatcher<bool>();
QFuture<bool> procfuture2 = QtConcurrent::run(this, &EraserBatch::processTile);
procwatcher2->setFuture(procfuture2);
```

You can do something like this:

```
// Not tested!

// Bundle QFutureWatcher and QFuture together.
template<typename T>
struct FutureStruct
{
    FutureStruct(QFutureWatcher<T>* w, const QFuture<T>& f)
        : watcher(w), future(f)
    {
        this->watcher->setFuture(this->future);
    }

    QFutureWatcher<T>* watcher; // Apparently QObjects can't be copied.
    QFuture<T> future;
};

// ...

std::vector< FutureStruct<bool> > futures;

// ...

void AddFuture()
{
    futures.push_back(FutureStruct<bool>(new QFutureWatcher<bool>(),
        QtConcurrent::run(this, &EraserBatch::processTile)));
}

// ...

futures[0].watcher; // gets you the first QFutureWatcher<bool>*
futures[0].future;  // gets you the first QFuture<bool>

futures[1].watcher; // gets you the second QFutureWatcher<bool>*
futures[1].future;  // gets you the second QFuture<bool>

// ...
```

Of course, because the `QFutureWatcher<bool>` was allocated with `new`, you need to `delete` it before the `futures` vector goes away:

```
for(std::vector< FutureStruct<bool> >::iterator i = futures.begin();
    i != futures.end(); ++i)
{
    delete i->watcher;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the `*`. What does the OP actually wants?

Answer (score 2):

RAII way if watchers are owned not only by the vector:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<QFutureWatcher<bool> > ProcWatcherPtr;
std::vector<ProcWatcherPtr> procWatchers;
```

RAII way if watchers are owned only by the vector:

```
typedef QFutureWatcher<bool> ProcWatcher
boost::ptr_vector<ProcWatcher> procWatchers;
```

or without memory allocation if it fits your needs:

```
std::vector<QFutureWatcher<bool> > procWatchers;
```